# valid signup information with account activation - Error: Expected true to be nil or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone please try to help me out in this error? I don't really understand what the error means to me.

```
test "valid signup information with account activation" do 
  get signup_path
  assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do 
    post users_path, params: {user: {name: "Example User",
                                     email: "user@example.com",
                                     password: "password",
                                     password_confirmation: "password"}}

    end
  assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
  user = assigns(:user)
  assert_not user.activated?

  #Try to log in before actication.
  log_in_as(user)
  assert_not is_logged_in?

  #Invalid activation token with valid email
  get edit_account_activation_path('invalid token',email: user.email)
  assert_not is_logged_in?

  #Valid activation token with invalid email
  get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
  assert_not is_logged_in?

  #Valid activation token with valid email
  get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token,email: user.email)
  assert user.reload.activated?
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'users/show'
  assert is_logged_in?
 end
```

This test is keep failing because of this error:

```
Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation [D:/RubyOnRails/RailsProjects/sample_app/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:53]:
Expected true to be nil or false
```

The Error on line 53 is coming from here.

```
Line 52 log_in_as(user)
Line 53 assert_not is_logged_in?
```

This is my methods

```
def is_logged_in?
   !session[:user_id].nil?
end

def log_in_as(user)
session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

Comment: Suresh you are assessing for too many activities for a single test. The error its getting is on line 53 as you only posted 32 lines its hard to say which is causing wrong out put can you please let us know which is line 53

Comment: One of the `assert_not`s is failing. More specifically, if you read the error message, it's the one on line `53`. However, there is **way too much** going on in this test! You should split it out into *at least* 5 separate tests! Remember that a test will "abort" upon the **first** assertion failure. This means if something fails near the top of your test, the other "scenarios" won't even be attempted.

Comment: As a rule of thumb (not something to be taken as gospel, but more of a guideline), you should aim to only have **one assertion per test**. having more is OK if they are *closely related*, or *sanity checks*. But not for testing totally different features like "sending an email on account create" vs "checking which template is loaded after logging in" vs "checking non-activated accounts can't log in".

Comment: Hi @TomLord thx for your feedback. Btw i have updated my above post.  I am not sure why the error is coming from line 53.

Comment: I think the test is failing because on Line 53 assert_not is_logged_in? It's returning true instead of false or nil. And i am using assert_not which expects to be false or nil. Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at what each step of your test is actually doing, to understand the error.

First, you "sign up" a user - most likely at the `UsersController#create` action (or whatever else your `routes.rb` file defines):

```
post users_path, params: {user: {name: "Example User",
                                 email: "user@example.com",
                                 password: "password",
                                 password_confirmation: "password"}}
```

Doing this creates a new `User` record, where `user.disabled == true`:

```
assert_difference 'User.count', 1
assert_not user.activated?
```

**Next, you wanted to test that a disabled user cannot log in**. The logic that dictates this is will be *within the login controller action*. My guess is that it will be in `SessionsController#create`, if such a thing exists in your application. It could also be placed somewhere more generic, like as a `before_action` in the `ApplicationController`.

In order to test this, you need to simulate a **real** sign-in action. I cannot say for sure what code this will require without seeing the rest of your application, but for example it could be something like:

```
post sessions_path, params: {user: {email: "user@example.com",
                                 password: "password"}}
```

Or if you want to make this a *true* integration test, you could even simulate filling in the form and clicking the "log in" button. What you have here currently is more akin to a controller test, not an integration test.

---

The method you were using previously:

```
def log_in_as(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

Is fine to use in tests that don't care about simulating a "real" login. But for tests that *do* care about the login being "real", you need to it the relevant controller action.

In this case, your logic for "not letting disabled users log in" was never actually being invoked; hence the failure.

If you want to make the error message clearer when using assertions like this, you can [include the error message](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions/assert_not) like so:

```
assert_not is_logged_in?, 'Disabled user was able to log in'
```

---

**Below is a complete example of what the tests could look like**. You may need to tweak the implementation slightly, depending on how your controllers are defined.

```
test "valid signup information with account activation" do 
  get signup_path
  assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do 
    post users_path, params: {user: {name: "Example User",
                                     email: "user@example.com",
                                     password: "password",
                                     password_confirmation: "password"}}

    end
  assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
  user = assigns(:user)
  assert_not user.activated?
end


test "cannot log in with disabled account" do
  user = user.create!(name: "Example User",
                      email: "user@example.com",
                      password: "password",
                      password_confirmation: "password")

  post login_path, params: { session: { email: "user@example.com",
                                        password: "password" } }

  assert_not is_logged_in?, 'Disabled user was able to log in'
end

test "cannot login with invalid activation token" do
  # ...
end

test "can login with valid activation token" do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: But the thing is assert_not is_logged_in? is returning true instead of false. So how i do solve this problem? The log_in_as(user) is working fine.

Comment: Like I said above: The issue is not that `log_in_as` *does not work*; the issue is that this is **faking** the log-in by just setting the `session[:user_id]` directly. In order for this test to pass, you will need to simulate a **real** login-in.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have attempted what you have told earlier on below

Comment: @Suresh I have updated my answer with one final attempt to show you how this could be done... I also found [the online workbook](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-a_test_for_valid_submission) you have been following!

Comment: Hi thank you Tom. I would like to ask you, do you know any best books for rails testing? As far as i am concern the rails tutorial doesn't teach you testing from stretch.